# Green potential and Hölder continuity

Tags: cv.complex-variables, potential-theory, green-function

Assume that $U$ is the unit disk and $g\in L^{3/2}(U)$. Define $$f(z) = \int_{U} \log\left|\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar w}\right|g(w)\frac{du \, dv}{\pi}, \ \ w=u+iv.$$ Is there an elementary proof of the fact that $f$ is $\alpha=2/3$ Hölder continuous on the unit disk?

Answer (score 1):

An elementary proof (~ 1 page) for the more general case of Riesz potentials in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (hence for the logarithmic potential or Green potential in $\mathbb{C}$), and for more general exponents (e.g. if $g\in L^p$ with $1<p<2$ when $n=2$, then the potential is $(2-2/p)$-Hölder continuous) can be found in the lecture note "Potential theory in the euclidean space" (1996) by Y. Mizuta.